Explicit example of a quintic threefold with 2875 distinct lines
A generic quintic threefold has 2875 lines. Is there an example of a quintic threefold explicitly defined by a polynomial that can be proven to have exactly 2875 distinct lines?
I am particularly interested in an answer in the following form. Oguiso-Yu (Section 2, arXiv:1504.05011) classified the automorphism groups of smooth quintic threefolds into 22 types. I would like to know one (or more, if possible) quintic threefold $X$ from their list such that $X$ has 2875 distinct lines and its automorphism group $Aut(X)\subset PGL_5(\mathbb{C})$ acts faithfully on those lines, i.e. the map from $Aut(X)$ into the symmetric group of the 2875 lines is injective.
I apologize for my ignorance in algebraic geometry as my background is in topology. I am aware of this math.stackexchange post (Lines on a Quintic Threefold) asking for a quintic threefold which can be shown to contain only finitely many lines. But it doesn't answer my question. In a comment, Nefertiti mentioned that Macaulay2 has a command command Fano(k,I) which will calculate the ideal of the Fano variety of k-planes inside the projective variety defined by the homogenous ideal $I$. I tried this approach for the quintic threefold $x^4y+y^4z+z^4w+w^4u+u^4x=0$ on my personal computer. The program got killed automatically after an hour. I guess my computer ran out of memory for this task. I am new to stackexchange and don't have enough reputation to comment on that post.
Thank you very much for any input.

Upon proving that some of the Galois groups of enumerative problems, among them the 2875 lines on the smooth quintic 3-fold in ${\Bbb P}^4$ is the full symmetric group, Harris writes "In particular, in every case in which current theory had failed to discern any intrinsic structure on the set of solutions -- it is proved here -- there is in fact none."

@Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks. How is that remark relevant here?

Probably isn’t, since the 2875 lines are of codim two, unlike for the cubic surfaces where the 27 lines are codim one

I tried to run the same command on your examples and I don't think it's running out of memory but maybe gives up on some sort of convergence since it complains about running numeric algorithms. Maybe there's a way to check specific $\mathbb{Q}$-examples by looking at their reductions to sufficiently large $\mathbb{Z}/p$? (Also, hi!)

Actually I got Macaulay to finish the computation for the second polynomial and it claims to produce 4005 solutions, so something is wrong (if the number of lines is $>2875$ then the variety of lines should be positive dimensional). One of the generators of the ideal produced by Fano(1, I) is of the form $\text{monomial} - 10^{16} \cdot \text{monomial}$, so I'm guessing that's causing numeric issues.

@ronno Special quintics, like the Fermat, can have infinite lines. Maybe then the Fano command might malfunction like that? Big integers like the ones you see shouldn’t be a problem

@Jan-MagnusØkland Yes, I am aware that the variety of lines can be positive dimensional but I also verified that the ideal Macaulay produces defines something $0$-dimensional. I wouldn't be suspicious if there were big numbers everywhere but the ideal had dozens of generators (necessarily, to be $0$ dimensional in the Grasmmannian) and that was the only coefficient other than $\pm 1$. I'm guessing the $p - \text{large} \cdot q$ term is supposed to just be $q$, and because of this perturbation it's turning some of the solutions into multiple.

However, I am a beginner at using Macaulay so it's possible that I'm misusing/misunderstanding something.

@ronno Hi! Thanks! I just realized that the second example $x^4y+y^5+z^5+w^5+u^5=0$ does have infinitely many lines. For example, it contains any line $[s:\zeta s :zt:wt:ut]$ where $\zeta^4=-1$ and $z^5+w^5+u^5=0$. That seems to be a 1-dimensional family of lines. So that's not an example to look at. Sorry about that. I will edit the question. I still want to know about the first example though, or any example of a generic quintic threefold. I also tried to compute the Fano(1,I) for the first example over $Z/pZ$ where $p=2,3,5,7$. My computer does not produce any results after hours.
